# How to get the type of a il2cpp class for GameObject.FindObjectsOfTypeAll() UnityEngine function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I am trying to use `GameObject.FindObjectsOfTypeAll()` in UnityEngine and it is asking for an
Il2Cpp class, and if i do `GameObject.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(Image))`
i get the error `cannot convert from "System.Type" to "Il2cppSystem.Type"`

I also tried using GameObject.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(Il2CppSystem.Type.GetType("Image"))
But this ends in a null reference exception.

This is what Im trying to do but it doesn't enter the foreach obviously

```
foreach (GameObject image in GameObject.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(Image)))
            {
                image.GetComponent<Image>().color = panelColor;
            }
```

and

```
foreach (GameObject image in GameObject.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(Il2CppSystem.Type.GetType("Image")))
            {
                image.GetComponent<Image>().color = panelColor;
            }
```

Comment: You might want to explain what a "GameObject.FindObjectsOfTypeAll()" is. Specifically, where does GameObject come from? What library is it? Perhaps, by adding those keywords in your question, you'll get attention from someone who's worked with that library.

Comment: @AndrewRondeau the question is tagged [`Unity3d`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/info) .. everyone a little bit familiar with it will know that [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) is one of the most basic types in Unity and [`Object.FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) is usually rather used directly via `UnityEngine.Object` ;)

Comment: Actually ses pretty odd since for the last 5 years **if** I head to deal with the typed version I always used `System.Type` ... in general in your case I would prefer to use the generic version `Object.FindObjectsOfType<Image>()` though

Answer (score 0):

```
Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(UnityEngine.UI.Image)
```

or

```
 Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<UnityEngine.UI.Image>()
```

maybe you using some namespace it also have "image" class.
So try put it full namespace of type .

Comment: That is using the generic version which is something completely different than using the version taking a `Type` parameter ;) In most cases it is preferred to use the generic if the type is not dynamic anyway though which seems to be the case here

Comment: yes generic  is better . it's not get type at runtime.